# default circle ProgressBar thickness etc

Tags: android-layout, android-xml, android-progressbar

I have the default circle ProgressBar:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlYL4.png

I would like to change the thickness, color and the corner radius (in an XML) Already, found some examples, but they don't work with the default circle.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml file in `drawable` folder.

> Drawable XML file

**progress_bar_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">
    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="2dp"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <gradient
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#ff00ff"
            android:endColor="#00ffffff"
            android:angle="0"/>

    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Start color and end Color of gradient you should change according to your need.

To change the thickness of progress bar  you change the thickness using `android:thickness` attribute of shape.

And add code to your layout xml file.

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_bg" />
```

android:layout_width and android:layout_height should be change according to your need.

I hope its Work for you.